# How to understand $\mathbb{Z}^n$-graded ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, graded-rings

I am reading Ringel's note and I encountered a question I have never met. The question is what's the meaning of a $\mathbb{Z}^n$-graded ring？ This is from the following:

"Note that the rings $U_q (n_ +(\Delta))$ and is $\mathbb{Z}^n$-graded, where we assign to $E_i$ the degree $e_i$. Given $d \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, we denote by  $U_q (n_ +(\Delta))_d$ the set of homogeneous elements of degree $d$." Which is from Ringel'note:

[Note picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIvS6.png)

Where $A^{'}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(v)$.

Comment: It's $\mathbb{Z}^n$, not $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Does that help?

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake. It's $\mathbb{Z}^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you know what a graded ring is. This definition can be generalized to a $G$-graded ring for any monoid $G$, by replacing the role of the natural numbers or the integers by the monoid $G$. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#G-graded_rings_and_algebras).

In this case, the grading is by the monoid $G = (\mathbb{Z}^n,+)$.

Comment: And what's the "homogeneous element"? And what's the multiplication, since it's not commutative?

Comment: In a graded ring, a homogeneous element is just an element which is in one of the subgroups in the direct sum decomposition - a general element is a finite sum of homogeneous elements.

Comment: The multiplication seems to be defined in the image you linked to, though it's hard to understand without further context. The definition of graded ring makes sense for non-commutative rings too. Anyway, the question you asked was "what is a $\mathbb{Z}^n$-graded ring?", and it seems Captain Lama and I have both answered that question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I canunderstand more about that.  I find that the homogeneous element of degree $d \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ is the multiplication in which the times $E_i$ appears is $d_i$.

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ is a ring and $G$ is any group, you can say that $R$ is $G$-graded if you have a direct sum decomposition $R = \bigoplus R_g$ as an additive group, such that $R_g\cdot R_h\subset R_{gh}$ for any $g,h\in G$. In particular it makes sense for $G=\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: Thanks. I can understand graded ring, but I don't know the definition of "homogeneous elements" and the multiplication.